# Read filename from command-line and use it outside main method

Tags: java, console-application

I have to write a program that counts the lines in a file, the file is specified when starting the program:

```
java CountText textFile.txt
```

In the main method I use this code to get the filename entered in cmd:

```
if ( args.length > 0 ) {
    String file = args[0];
}
```

Outside the main method I want to refer to this filename again:

```
public void Lines() throws Exception {      
    FileReader fr = new FileReader ( file );
```

The symbol can't be found (which I don't get because main method is public and static?). I feel like it's a simple solution, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT: Solved by Hovercraft Full Of Eels (also Travis). It is a scope issue which is solved by passing the String into the method via its parameter.

```
public class CountText {
public static void main ( String args[] ) throws Exception {
    CountText count = new CountText();

    if ( args.length > 0 ) {
        String file = args[0];
        count.Lines( file );
        count.Words( file );
        count.Characters( file );
    }
}

public void Lines ( String file ) throws Exception {        
    FileReader fr = new FileReader ( file );
```

Comment: Why not simply pass the String into the method via its parameter: `public void lines(String file) {...}` (file's a bad name for a String variable though -- you'd think that it should represent a File object, not a String)

Comment: post your code. I think you are probably declaring some of the variables outside of context.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels solved the problem. Thank you, sir.

Comment: If all methods are using the same String, then much better is to simply pass it in *once* into the class via a constructor parameter.

Comment: When an answer helps you to get *your* answer, you should mark the green check next to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're encountering here is a scope problem.  Your variable is defined in the main function, so another function cannot access it.  We say that the variable file is **local** to the main function.

One way to use the file variable inside your Lines method so that it accepts a string argument, which you can then pass to it.  That would look like

```
public void Lines( String fileName ) throws Exception {
    // rest of the code here
}
```

So then you can call the method like so

```
if ( args.length > 0 ) {
    String file = args[0];
    Lines( file );
}
```

Comment: If my answer is sufficient for you, feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

The main method is an entry point for a program.

The main method can even be in a different class that the one containing the program logic.

You must declare a private instance variable for the file path and pass it in the constructor of the class.

In the main method, you create an instance of your class.

```
public class SomeClass {

    private String filePath;

    // this is the constructor of the class
    public SomeClass(String filePath){
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public void lines() throws Exception {      
        FileReader fr = new FileReader ( this.filePath );
        ...
        ...
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SomeClass o = new SomeClass(args[0]);

    }

}
```

As I said before you can even delete the main method from SomeClass and move it to, say, MainClass:

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SomeClass o = new SomeClass(args[0]);

    }
}
```

And you can have more fun: you can even receive more than one file in the command line, instantiate SomeClass more than once, then process each file in batch, since file path is an instance variable, every object is separated and distinct:

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();

        for(String s: args){
           list.add(new SomeClass(s));  // create an instansce for each filename in args
        }

        for(SomeClass o: list){
           o.lines();    // run method on each file
        }

    }
}
```

That's the magic of OOP in action !

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a field in your class named `file` with type `String`.

Something like this

```
public class SomeClass {

private static String file;

public static void main(String[] args) {
file = args[0];
}

}
```

Comment: Hm, and that won't throw an error for trying to use a non-static variable in a static context?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My bad, I'll fix that :p